# Convert a decimal higher than 9 int to char in C

Tags: c

To write into a log file, some pointer list (in C language), i would like to convert my int * into a character array before to write it, in the log file.

I know that to convert a decimal to a char buffer we could use something like below but my values could be higher than 9 and this didn't work for that.

```
int data = 5;
char cData = data + '0';
```

Have you any solutions ?

Best Regards.

Comment: If you're using `printf` or `fprintf` to write the log entries, just use a `%d` format in your format string.

Comment: That's not possible, a `char` can only hold a single digit character.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want here as a result. A single character will not display as more than one digit. If you want to compress an integer to a single character, it will have a very limited range, and it won't look always look like a digit. If you want the int value 10 to come out looking like "10", that's two characters, not a single character, so then you have to deal with strings.

Comment: Even if you're using this in some JNI related code, the question and the code it asks about is not related to JNI so that tag shouldn't be used. The problem is a pure C problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes it's not mentionned to my post but It's C, by using JNI and It's why I'm added this tag, It was if some JNI function could resolve my problem ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't store a decimal more than 9 in a `char`. I would recommend you to use a `char array` to store decimal greater than 9 using `sprintf()` defined in `<stdlib.h>` like this.

```
int data = 224;
char arr[10];
sprintf(arr, "%d", data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, As i'm saying at @ikegami, I'm looking for something difficult while, it's a simple question!
Another time, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

A `char` can't hold both `'1'` and `'0'`. You would need at least two `char`. This is what the `printf` family does. `printf %d` will convert an `int` to a string that's its decimal representation.

Since you said you want to output the result, `printf` or `fprintf` might be the best options. If you want to build the string in an array, `snprintf`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm looking for something difficult while, it's a simple question!